# How do I set a highlight colour for text in a UIWebView?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uiwebview

Our app uses a lot of custom `UITableViewCell`s.  Most have a few extra `UILabel`s, and in those we can set the highlightTextColor property of the label so that when a user selects the cell, the text changes to white.

However, some of them require extra formatting, so we use `UIWebView`s with HTML contents; the text colour is set by the CSS embedded in the HTML.  When the cell is selected, the text stays whatever colour is set in the CSS.

Is it possible to set a highlight colour for the text in the `UIWebView`?  If so, how - is there a special CSS selector?  I tried `-webkit-tap-highlight-color` but it had no effect.

Answer (score 0):

As it appears, you can't. The `-webkit-tap-highlight-color` selector is used when you tap (or even tap and hold) over a link. However, the selection feature is native for iOS, and there isn't any known way to override its settings, be the highlight color or anything else.

You could try the `::selection` selector, but I have had no success at all. In regular browsers it works like this:

```
p.normal::selection {
    background:#cc0000;
    color:#fff;
}

p.moz::-moz-selection {
    background:#cc0000;
    color:#fff;
}

p.webkit::-webkit-selection {
    background:#cc0000;
    color:#fff;
}
```

However, in mobile webkit it has no effect.